# Problem with module installation on staging subfolder (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, module, installation, staging

I have created a staging magento copy of live site on a sub folder, everything goes fine until now.

When I want to install module, and **run magento module:status** doesn't appear on the list.

The folder of module is on **app/code**, but nothing happens.

Any clue about this problem?

Thanks!!!

**[More Info]**

I'm trying to install this module https://store.plumrocket.com/twitter-facebook-login-magento2-extension.html

**module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Plumrocket_SocialLoginFree" setup_version="2.2.0">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Customer" />
        <module name="Plumrocket_Base" />
    </sequence>
</module>
```

**registration.php**

`\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Plumrocket_SocialLoginFree',
    __DIR__
);`

Comment: What is the error that's is thrown ?

Comment: I upload the module manually, on app/code, the names are correct and also the content. But when in console I run magento module:status , it doesn't appear on List of disabled modules, so I can't enable this

Comment: Have You run the php bin/magento setup:upgrade this command.

Comment: @Learing_Coder I've already run this command, but nothing new appears.

Answer (score 0):

Please check in your module there registration.php exist with below code with no typo:

```
     <?php
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
   'Namespace_Modulename',
    __DIR__
    );
```

and also module.xml
etc/module.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Namespace_Modulename" setup_version="1.9.1">
    <sequence/>
</module>
```

Comment: I've checked those files and everything is ok. I don't know what could happen. Maybe permissions on folders?

Comment: @gaby1990 Can you please share your code for registration and module file in question. May be We can help you

Comment: I edited the question to add more information. Thanks for helping me!